# jquery children - not found

Tags: jquery, html, children

I'm trying to develop simple abalone game using html5/jquery but I discovered the problem I can't exmplain to myself.

There is a board, which is drawn by jquery and also some moveable balls (also drawn by jquery)

I'd like to send ajax request to the server based on current DOM structure.

I have source code (from firebug) like this: (it's the tile with some id, including some image and maybe the ball)

```
<div class="tile ui-droppable" id="tile0-5" style="position: absolute; top: 364px; left: 0px; width: 72px; height: 72px;">
    <img src="/abalone/www/images/tile.png" width="72" height="72" alt="tile">
    <img class="ball white-ball ui-draggable" src="/abalone/www/images/white-ball.png" width="36" height="36" alt="white-ball" id="ball0-5" style="position: absolute; top: 18px; left: 18px; z-index: 99999;">
</div>
```

so assuming id of the tile being tile0-5 I try to write into console (but niether regular script works)

```
$("#tile0-5").children()
```

I have expected both images - tile and the ball, but only the tile was returned. I already try to add selector like

```
$("#tile0-5").children(".ball")
```

which returned empty array (I mean no result)

this is the last problem I face, can some help me please? I use the most recent jquery stable release

thanks a lot, guys

EDIT:
I also tried

```
    $("#tile0-5").find(".ball")
```

which also didn't work.

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: It works in my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KBK2z/1/

Comment: Are you sure you have only one element with id `tile0-5`?

Comment: did you tried `$("#tile0-5").find(".ball")`?

Comment: I think @SamDufel is on the right track. Children shouldn't return the element corresponding to the selector. I think you've got this DIV inside another element with the same id.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/78HxM/; have you used jQuery UI drag drop to move your element in the DOM tree?

Comment: well, it's difficult to post my code to fiddle as it depends on server side :-/

Comment: @SamDufel: I am sure, moreover ids are generater by algorithm and also in the cript I don't care about id, I select every tile by using $(".tile") a then I use $.each - it doesn't work either

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward: Yes, I move the ball-image into proper tile when dragged&dropped, but even when I don't move any ball, I can't select it :-/ anyway, the html file consist of hidden template-images and I build the map using jquery... but when DOM is updated and properly displayed, I can't see any reason why it should not work :-/

Comment: Can you give us a little more context on where are you trying to call `$("#tile0-5").children(".ball")` is it after an event or something? if you can please post the function

Comment: make sure you don't have multiple divs with the same IDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one also more Helpful!!!

```
$("#tile0-5 .ball")
```

Output contains a list of elements which have ball class in tile0-5 Id Container

Comment: yes, I know about this possibility and thanx for it. It really works, nontheless I'm about to use $.each() in order to iterate through all .tile and I'd like to check whether it contains the ball or not. So I guess I need children() or so... I think building my own string selector by concat. ids and classes is clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#tile0-5 img").each(function()
    {
        if($(this).hasClass('ball'))
        {
            alert($(this).attr("src"));
        }   
    });
});
</script>
```

this function help you to find all images having class 'ball' in each function

Comment: thanks, it works, but I have fixed functionality (not looking for some different solution) - I am just wondering why my solution doesn't work even though it should.

Answer (score 0):

Required context, thanks for help

```
function endTurnButtonClicked () {
$.log("Sending data to server...");
$($.endTurnButton).prop('disabled', true);

var data = {};
tiles = $(".tile");
$.each(tiles, function (key, tile) {
    //make 2D array
    if (! $.isArray(data)) data = Array();
    if (! $.isArray(data[$(tile).data("row")])) data[$(tile).data("row")] = Array();

    //var ball = $(tile).children(".ball"); //does not find any
    var tileId = $(tile).attr("id");
    var ball = $("#" + tileId + " .ball"); //this works, but it's so clumsy

    //---- rest of code (no problem here) ----
    var color = $.NONE; 

    if ($(ball).length == 1) {
         color = $(ball).data("color");
    }
    else if ($(ball).length > 1) {
        color = "ERROR";
    }
    data[$(tile).data("row")][$(tile).data("column")] = color;
});

$.ajax({
    url:    $.linkNextRound(),
    cache:  false,
    dataType:   'json',
    data:   data,
    type:   'POST',
    success:    function (data) {
        $.log("Success", "success");
        waitForNextRound();
    },
    error:  function (data) {
        $.log("Error while sending data to server.", "error");
        $($.endTurnButton).prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

}